# C++ Classname Function()

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

I was recently giving an online quiz on c++ and a question came that had similar syntax as

```
class className
{
     public:
     constructor()
     {
         print("ABC");
     }
}

int main()
{
    className ABC();
    return 0;
}
```

I thought it would not compile but rather it compiled and ran without having any effect, I am interested as to what feature this is and in which case do we use this?

Comment: `className ABC();` declares a function pointer. Use `className ABC;` to create a local object. And a method named `constructor` isn't a constructor.

Comment: Also the constructor is a function with the same name as the class, like `className() { ...` not a method named constructor.

Comment: @AlexShesterov It does not declare a function pointer.

Comment: Such example [didn't compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lTF1vJYruVQebH7i) for me.

Comment: @Swordfish https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/my-attempt-at-value-initialization-is-interpreted-as-a-function-declaration-and

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `className ABC();` DOES NOT declare a function pointer.` No links you throw at me change that fact.

Comment: @Swordfish - Correct, it declares a function.

Comment: Does not compile on Ubuntu, g++v7.3:  error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘constructor’ with no type [-fpermissive]     for line  "constructor()...";  Also, the code requires a ';' after class definition.

Comment: my bad, it declares a function.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted code won't compile. Ignoring that there are 2 reasons it doesn't do anything.

1. `className ABC();` declares a function. To call the default constructor of a class simply omit the brackets: `className ABC;`
2. `className` has a method called `constructor` but no contructor so doesn't print anything when it is constructed.